# Send Password Reset Email to all users at once

Tags: users, emails, activation, plugin-sproutemail

I have a bunch (about 3000) of imported users from a website, which is currently on a redesign.
When the site is finished, I would like to send an email to all users,
saying that the site is relaunched, has a new structure ect. and therefore they have to set a new password.

I found nothing in the Craft settings, as well in the forum.

Do I have to write a plugin?
Or can I achieve this with the Sprout Email plugin?
I saw, there is a event "When a user logs in".

This could also work for me: a users logs in and gets automatically
to the a page to set a new password.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the Sprout Email plugin can do anything to help you or not, but I can think of a few options that would involve simple, [custom](https://pluginfactory.io) [plugins](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins).

Every user has a "Require a password reset on next login" that an administrator can set from the CP under their settings.  You probably don't want to do that manually for 3,000 users, but a simple plugin (or a simple SQL query) could set the `passwordResetRequired` column in the `craft_users` table in the database to `1`.

If you wanted to send an email and include a password reset link in that email ahead of time, a plugin would change that column to `1` for all users and follow similar logic in the [UsersController](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController) for getting the password reset link and include that in the email body that you'd send to every user programatically.

Comment: the sql query route would probably be easiest if OP has access to the database administration

Comment: did anyone write a plugin for this? I am in the same situation. Although I might just write them a manual on how to reset the password. But it's rather lame and customers tend to get confused very easily. Anyone?